# Django plain-text email template generates \n after template tags

Tags: python, django, email

Interesting issue here: I have plain-text emails sent by my Django app, with the following code:

```
email_context = dict()
email_context['to'] = user.display_name
email_context['new'] = user_data['new']
email_context['for_reminder'] = user_data['for_reminder']

plaintext = get_template('email/notification.txt')
text_content = plaintext.render_to_string(email_context)

html = get_template('email/notification.html')
html_content = html.render(email_context)

email = EmailMultiAlternatives(
    subject='Assignments',
    body=text_content,
    to=[user.email],
    reply_to=[settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL],
)

# email.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")

email.send()
```

the 'email/notification_base.txt' template looks like such:

```
Dear {{ to }},
{% if new %}
You have been assigned to the following NEW cases:
{% block new %}
{% endblock %}
{% endif %}
{% if for_reminder %}
You still have the following previously assigned cases, which need your attention:
{% block for_reminder %}
{% endblock %}
{% endif %}
Thank you for your assistance.

Sincerely,
The Team
```

the 'email/notification.txt' template just extends base:

```
{% extends 'email/notification_base.txt' %}

{% load common_tags %}
{% load common_filters %}

{% block new %}
{% for dispute in new %}
Case #: {{ dispute.case_id.no}}
Assignment date: {{ dispute.assignment_date }}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

{% block for_reminder %}
{% for dispute in for_reminder %}
Case #: {{ dispute.case_id.no }}
Assignment date: {{ dispute.assignment_date }}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

My problem with it is, that the email it generates and sends to the addressee, actually gets rendered with a NEWLINE in every spot where the template had {% something %} tags. This results in a very unevenly formatted email text. As an example, if both blocks were missing the email would look like:

```
Dear Someone,



Thank you for your assistance.

Sincerely,
The Team
```

Are there any ways around this problem?

Comment: Send us the contents of the other `blocks`, i.e. `block new` and `block reminder`.

Comment: Don't put newlines in your template. You have one after every template instruction.

Comment: updated above...

Comment: So that is just my problem Klaus D. - can I prevent the rendering backend from putting a newline after every template instruction?

Comment: I would suggest adding conditionals around the content that doesn't always get rendered.  This would remove the \n you find.  `{% if new %}` loop through `new` `{% endif %}`